# Ive installed both the graphics drivers; Is that bad?

Tags: drivers

I couldn't get one of my games to run so I installed the 'Additional drivers' graphics card driver for my computer but I already installed the one from ATI website.

Would this cause any trouble/slow down?

If so how can I fix this, I needed the 'Additional drivers' one to make my game run :S

So basically..
Would this cause any trouble/slow down?

Thanks, Jamie.

Comment: I guess your graphics will be twice as intense. :-)

Comment: I think you are worrying about a problem which hasn't happened yet. Do you see any issues when playing the game? If so, ask this question with some detail as to symptoms. If not - problem solved. (I think you'll probably be fine, but who knows...)

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't.  When you install through jockey it usually takes care of all the deactivating of other drivers and such for you.  This is the bonus of using jockey.

I'm a fan of getting things rolled into debs and leveraging tools that already exist instead of using svn/git updates per piece of software...

Comment: Thanks! Will make another question or dig this one up if anything happens soon :-) Only switched to 11.10 Ubuntu Recently so wasn't sure.